# R-Studio Package Installation Strange Response

Tags: rstudio, install.packages

I've had an issue that started yesterday with R Studio. When I install a package, even a small one, it fills the screen with an ever increasing progress line. The installation never finishes. The installation does finish in base R but the progress line still keeps growing. I'm running OSX Yosemite, R version 3.2.2, RStudio Version 0.99.893 (this also happens with the previous version of RStudio as well). Any ideas on why this may have started occurring? I teach a lot and use R, so I can pinpoint the change to yesterday morning, without any software changes to that point in previous weeks.

Comment: check if `utils::install.packages` instead of `install.packages` helps

Comment: No luck in this case. I still just get the continuous progress line until R Studio eventually just has to shut down. Very strange.

Comment: Check if you are able to install packages via the terminal or OS X R GUI.